# clearing google analytics cached data - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I am working on an iOS app in which I have integrated Google Analytics for tracking different events and crashes but what I want is that when my app crashes then only crash report should be sent to google analytics. Let me explain again

if app runs smoothly it should send all the data to google server

if app runs without internet then google caches all the data and sends when internet is available and it should run

now this one is important.
If app runs without internet then google caches all data, but when app is offline it is crashed and when analytics SDK tries to send the data to the server on next restart it should only send crash report instead of all the activity performed by user when he was inactive.

Comment: Did you got an answer?  I have similar problem.